# Cant delete object after installing devise & cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I installed Devise and Cancan. My user has role super_admin with options shown below:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user
  can :manage, :all
end
```

all works well except deleting elements. When I'm trying to delete object:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', place, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

it keeps logging me out and redirecting to sign_in page

My class looks like that:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!
   load_and_authorize_resource
```

Comment: It would help if you add the relevant part of the log file while this behavior is reproduced. Empty the log file with `> log/development.log` command just before clicking on `Destroy link`, and then get the full output of the file after clicking the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

My layout file did not have authenticity_token tag

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

so POST and DELETE requests couldn't have been authenticated.